# Не назначаются стили элементу

Tags: javascript, css

Всем доброго дня! 
Меня сейчас наверное заминусуют. Но у меня нет идей, почему у меня не назначаются стили: получаю элементы через querySelectorAll:

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-left span');
spans[0].style.display = "None";
```

Но ничего не происходит. Приведу скриншот консоли браузера для наглядности
:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, почему не применяется style.display к элементу, ведь я ее применяю непосредственно к span. Продолжает отображаться как display:block, несмотря на то, что я назначил None и style.display равен none. Может, это какая-то особенность ссылок на элементы, полученные через querySelectorAll, только для чтения? 20-минутный поиск по гуглу не дал ответа

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ytfchgx6/ Все работает

Comment: Вы хотите только первый элемент скрыть?

Comment: @Arsen, да не важно. Не меняется даже 1

Comment: У меня две странности: 1. Я хочу чтобы при открытии меню слова появлялись плавно. Для этого делаю setInterval с периодом 25 мс и в цикле прогоняю каждый элемент span, назначая каждому новое значение opacity и делаю остановку clearInterval на op=1, то есть при отсутствии прозрачности. Но у меня работает только первое назначение. Дальше по вышеизложенному сценарию. А вот потом на Decrease_Menu назначение style не работает вообще

Comment: @nicolaa, выложил страницу в [сеть](http://vedmark.ru/left_menu.html). Может, глянете?

Comment: @digital-mag скрипт из Вашего вопроса рабочий, вся проблема в Вашем скрипте появления левого меню, он постоянно ставит для `span` - `display:block` и `opacity:0.5` Вам лучше подправить вопрос, с указание всех скриптов, которые установлены